# Switching kernels in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:
  **python3    /home/vijay/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2**
```

I am Not able to switch Kernel from python3 to python 2 in Jupyter notebook.

On starting jupyter notebook, following commands are displayed

```
JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /home/vijay/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab**
JupyterLab v0.27.0
Known labextensions:
[I 10:51:15.216 NotebookApp] Running the core application with no additional extensions or settings
[I 10:51:15.255 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/vijay
[I 10:51:15.255 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
```

Answer (score 1):

If the kernel from another conda environment is not visible in Jupyter, have a look at the [nb_conda_kernels](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels) package. It finds existing conda environments and dynamically adds ipython kernels to Jupyter.